# How to get progress status for a video file upload in flutter

Tags: flutter, dio, video-upload, flutter-streambuilder

I need the video upload stream to show the upload progress status.

I have tried using Dio but here the video file size is getting increased also not playing after uploading.

```
await Dio().put(
          uploadURL,
          data: await videoFile!.readAsBytes(),
          onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
          print('$sent $total');
        },
    );
```

Can anyone please help me regarding this or any better option to get the upload stream?